# SSRS Reference textbox value from Report VB Code

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, business-intelligence

I need to write a function in SSRS Report Code that takes a value from a textbox of my report. Is it possible to reference the value of a specific textbox in VB Report Code?

Thank you!